# How do I make my inline-block table expand to 100% width?

Tags: html, css

This is my code below and I'm trying to make it look like this image: [image]

I'm unsure of how to expand the table header all the way to the right. I also don't know how to add more spacing between the bottom border.

For the lazy my code shows this: [image]

```css
font-family:Arial;
 font-size:12px;
 width:800px;

}
table {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cfdaf1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #cfdaf1;
  padding: 3px;
}
td {
  padding: 10px
}
#headerMenu {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 125px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#contactTable {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
#tableHeader {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
#ul li:before {
  content: '►';
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableHeader" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Key Skills</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is a main summary of my skills.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul id="ul" style="list-style-type: none">
        <li>Negotiating (Intermediate)</li>
        <li>Access (Beginner)</li>
        <li>Accounting (Beginner)</li>
        <li>Sales Auditing (Expert)</li>
        <li>Invoicing (Intermediate)</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp.  And before you ask, no, I don't think you can do this with actual tables.

Comment: Do you know why making the table header an inline-block makes it only go to the width of the content in the table instead of the whole page? Is there a way to change this because setting the width to 100% didn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think using a `table` and set it's `display: inline-block` is a good idea, revise it with `display: table; width: 100%` in CSS should make it fill the width, also I would wrap it inside a `<div class="container">` for better CSS maintenance

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/Zay_DEV/a5zwgjz3/

### Bonus -

This example should implemented what all you want: https://jsfiddle.net/Zay_DEV/a5zwgjz3/2/

Comment: That's what I originally had, but I didn't know how to make the white border around the heading without making it an inline-block.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a cleaner and tableless version, but still using `display: flex;`:
follows: https://jsfiddle.net/vowpzf47/